# Using MongoDB with Chicago Boss

Tags: mongodb, erlang, chicagoboss

I'm a newbie to Erlang and I'm using Chicago Boss for a small web project. I have had no issues working with the in-memory db but when I configured it to use mongodb it doesn't go quite as expected. Below is my boss.config database section.

```
{db_host, "127.0.0.1"},
    {db_port, 27017 },
    {db_adapter, mongodb},
%    {db_username, "boss"},
%    {db_password, "boss"},
    {db_database, "asm_dashboard"},
```

I have made sure mongodb is running. I have tried installing mongodb-erlang(https://github.com/comtihon/mongodb-erlang) both manually and using rebar but I still end up with the same exception:

```
[error] gen_server <0.182.0> terminated with reason: {'module could not be loaded',[{mongo,connect,[{"127.0.0.1",27017}],[]}
```

Please assist.

Comment: Is `mongodb` added to the application list in your app.src file?

Comment: @matov yes. It looks like this: {application, asm_dashboard, [
        {description, "My Awesome Web Framework"},
        {vsn, "0.0.1"},
        {modules, []},
        {registered, []},
        {applications, [kernel, stdlib, crypto, mongodb]},
        {env, []}
    ]}.

Answer (score 0):

- First, can you post your whole boss.config file ?
- Try this template of mysql DB, I think it is the same, but it should be declared at etc/web.conf

> ```
> %% Mysql DB Config of ChicagoBoss
> {db_schema, "your_db_name"}.
> {db_username, "boss"}.
> {db_password, "boss"}.
> {dp_ip, "127.0.0.1"}.
> {db_port, 27017 }.
> {pool_size, 10}.
> ```